# GnoMAD's Gnomes locations

Tags: darksiders-2

I'm working on doing all the collection side-quests in Darksiders 2, but I cannot figure out where all the gnomes are for the GnoMAD's Gnomes collection quest. I randomly found the one in the City of the Dead, but have no clue where the others are. Anyone got the location for all the gnomes yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you still haven't found them, here's a video on Youtube, showing the locations of the gnomes:
 [All gnome locations](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvLJqLzhju8&feature=player_embedded)

A text version which i copied below can be found [here](http://www.cheatcc.com/xbox360/darksiders2cheatscodes.html#.UDZQyKOIyHg).

**Gnome 1**

*City Of The Dead – Floor 4 :*
At the northwest balcony, look for a hidden passage. You will find it behind a turning ledge that you can grab onto. Open the door with the switch, turn around and jump onto the post, then jump to the wall and wall run left. Return to the hand holds, and use Death's Split Soul to get off the nearby pressure plate, exposing a secret room.

**Gnome 2**

*The Ivory Citadel – Floor 3:*
After purifying the pool on top of the western-most tower, return to the northern passage that was previously covered in ooze on the third floor. To get back to the tower's top floor, follow the aquaduct, and climb the wall, but do not leave through the door. Instead, drop down to the balcony below, and climb back up to the top of the tower.

**Gnome 3**

*The Weeping Crag – Floor 3:*
To find the secret area, you must run into a pressure plate / rising platform puzzle in the third floor of The Weeping Crag. Past the platform is a portal. Open it, then turn east, and use the stairs, turning north and looking up at the ceiling for another portal to open. Activate it, then return to the previous portal —- the two portals should now be linked, and you will fall out of the ceiling portal into a secret room. Inside the treasury, dive around the northern waters to find a secret underwater tunnel.

**Gnome 4**

*The Black Stone – Floor 1 (Present):*
Wait until after you have unlocked the door in the past. When you return to the Great Foyer, check the northern ridge for hand holds. Descend the ledges, and return to the present through the portal. While in the present, climb back up using the hand holds to the north, and go through the now open western-most door. The Gnome is located further down the hall.

Comment: There we go! :D Was missing the Weeping Crag one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One can be found in the Weeping Crag after you get the Voidwalker inside that little "dungeon" they have there. Its in the only room you need the voidwalker to get up to.

Answer (score 0):

One is in the Black Stone. Right before the boss battle area, go into the present. Backtrack out of the door you came out of when you came from the past. (Other side of the Skeleton Key door, but in the present).

Answer (score 0):

Vince's description means that once you purify the second irrigation thing in the Ivory Citadel, go to the top and follow the spout going to the right side of the area (vantage point from the giant staircase leading up). Once you drop onto the turn follow the trail a bit until you are over a once corrupted hole in the wall. Drop down onto the area where that is, go into the hole in the wall and floating above a rock is one of the GnoMAD's Gnomes.

Answer (score -1):

where at in the city of the dead i found one when your doing the crystal spire i think whichever place you have to purify the water its around the last place u purify at youll have a tower and u use the portals to do it one of the arc things on the bottom one at top any who if facing the tower the pool with the gnome is to the right theres a hole in the wall and at first its full of corruption but after you cleanse the place your good to go and thats where i found that gnome.

i know that my description will probably screw the hell out of you sorry haha